# App submission: iTunes Connect Device Family

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

So I submitted the binary for my app and realised the device family (on the binary details page) is set to: iPhone / iPod Touch

I can't remember where I set this, but at the time I didn't want my app available on iPad. Now I realise I may aswell let iPad users play it, how do I change this setting so that iPad users can download it aswell?

Maybe it was set when I created the app on iTunes connect itself :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPad users can always run an iPhone/iPod touch app, no matter what you choose.  The device family indicates whether it is *iPad only*, *optimized for* iPhone/iPod touch (i.e. will run in the iPhone-in-iPad environment on an iPad), or *universal* (i.e. contains UI for both classes of devices).

Comment: Thanks but it's the second comment on this apps thread which is confusing: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/25498
Can you explain how he managed to do that lol?

Comment: My guess is that was a run time check. I believe you are actually forbidden (by App Store guidelines) from implementing such a check. But that's a question to take up with Apple. Note the app installed but didn't run; that tells you it was not the App Store blocking it. (Try installing an iPad only app on an iPhone. That is truly blocked by the App Store - it won't even appear in the store.)